# Change region using npx serverless to deploy on AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework

I uploaded to AWS CloudFront my Next JS app, with the following commands:

1. Creating my Nextjs app:

   `npx create-next-app`
2. Create a serverless app with npx serverless using aws-nodejs template:

   `npx serverless create --template aws-nodejs`
3. Updated my serveless.yml defining as serveless next component:

   ```
   myNextApp:
     component: "@sls-next/serverless-component@1.17.0"
   ```
4. Finally deploying my app in CloudFront:

   `npx serverless`

This work fine! Only a doubt.... my Cloud front distribution has as origin S3 located as default in  us-east-1, ¿how can I change the origin S3 region? I need it will be in eu-central-1. Is it possible to change the S3 region on deployment?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. You can't change the server region afterwards. I deleted everything (.serverless and .next-serverless folders that were created) and changed the serverless.yml.
Add the following in your serverless.yml file:

```
myNextApp:

  component: "@sls-next/serverless-component@1.17.0"

  inputs:

    bucketName: nameforyourbucket

    bucketRegion: eu-central-1
```

And deploy using npx serverless